# "Suggested Edit" feature? implementations?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, schema, database

For some content on my site I would like to let user submit suggested edit (just like in facebook when you edit the info of a venue).

I am thinking of having an extra table to store the suggestion and let an admin review those entry before committing the change. However consider that most website with user generated content has this feature, I would want to know the establish/optimal way to implement this.
(I am using mysql and mongodb)

Comment: extra table should work fine.

Comment: For a simple real-world How-to: Look at wikipedia, they're doing exactly this. The software behind wikipedia is called `mediawiki`.